# Can I asynchronously create and bind ViewHolders?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

Has anyone had experience with asynchronous creation of demanding view holders due to too much rendering time? Is that a good approach?

Comment: Rendering outside of the UI thread seems like a bad idea...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it from another thread asynchronously. For all view related task either creation or updating, it should be performed from the Main(UI) thread only.